# How to change column names from numbers to names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

I want to change the columnnames, for example: "2018-12-31 00:00:00" to "year_2018".
How can I do that?

Comment: Please share the text of your data frame in your question, not image.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts

Comment: whats the dtypes of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move the non-date columns in to the index, then use replace and reset_index:

```
df = df.set_index('CashFlows')
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: 'year_'+str(x.year))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at df.columns, find the name of the column and dtype.

```
df.rename(columns={'foo':'bar'},inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following dataframe

```
       2018-12-31 00:00:00   2019-12-31 00:00:00      2020-12-31 00:00:00
0           blah                blah                     blah
1           blah                blah                     blah
```

just do

```py
from dateutil import parser
df.columns = [parser.parse(c).strftime('year_%Y') for c in df.columns]
df
```

OUTPUT

```
        year_2018      year_2019     year_2020
0          blah          blah          blah
1          blah          blah          blah
```